# Javascript, check if element has left the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to test if a `<div>` has been scrolled out of view.

This is what I have so far,

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    var divBottom    = $('#home').offset().bottom; 
    var windowTop    = $(window).scrollTop();           
    var windowBottom = windowTop + $(window).height();  

    if (divBottom >= windowTop) {
        console.log("yes");
    } else {
        console.log("no");
    }
});
```

No matter where I scroll, nothing is logged.

What I was trying to test is if the bottom of the div has gone past the top of the window.

Comment: this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`divBottom` is `undefined`. You can use the `top` offset of the element and then calculate it's bottom value by adding it's height to the top, like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremija/UASUW/).

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    var $home = $('#home');
    var divBottom     = $home.offset().top + $home.height(); 
    var windowTop    = $(window).scrollTop();           

    console.log(divBottom, windowTop);

    if (divBottom >= windowTop) {
        console.log("yes");
    } else {
        console.log("no");
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for saying *exactly* what I was going to say but 3 minutes quicker ;)

Comment: `$("#home").offset().top + $("#home").height()` violates DRY. Prefer `var $home = $("#home"), divBottom = $home.offset().top + $home.height();` instead.

Comment: Yes many thanks for the answer! I just chucked 3 console logs in to see that my var bottom was "undefined" and doing offset top + height is the obvious answer i over looked! thanks again guys

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. @NiettheDarkAbsol You're right, but this was only a sketch. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

There's a very useful [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) function that could help here.

```
var divposition = document.getElementById('home').getBoundingClientRect();
if( divposition.left+divposition.width < 0) {
    // element is off to the left of the view
}
if( divposition.top+divposition.height < 0) {
    // element is off the top of the view
}
if( divposition.top > window.innerHeight) {
    // element is off the bottom of the view
}
if( divposition.left > window.innerWidth) {
    // element is off to the right of the view
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var myTop        = $('#home').offset().top;  // the top y location of your element
var windowTop    = $(window).scrollTop();           // the top of the window
var windowBottom = windowTop + $(window).height();  // the bottom of the window
```

then

```
if (myTop > windowTop && myTop < windowBottom) {
```

Comment: This fires when the div is fully on screen, I'm trying to get it to fire when the div has just left the screen, 'divBottom > screen top'

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
//your code 
});
```

Comment: I think scroll is not a problem here as it is always giving "no". The div position calculation is not proper here.